# Laravel: Route not found error:

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am writing code for email verification and My url is being generated as:

`http://example.com/auth/verify/InR9Jn%2FF6OpDpBlUpw5fXfbMgT6thonODPua0iX4AKI%3D`

I am using `urlencod` to encode it after `base64` and I am getting `Not Found Exception` for the route because of `%` sign in it. Route is defined as:

```
Route::get(
    'auth/verify/{confirmation_code}',
```

How to resolve it? How can I make % sign acceptable?

Comment: but you didn't put controller and action. You give only params when it's have be triggered

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you forgot to set the name of controller and action.

```
Route::get('auth/verify/{confirmation_code}', 'NameOfYourController@action');
```

Comment: I think we can assume that he did that already. The problem is that he is simply not hitting the uri, which has nothing to do with above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe encode the '%' sign in the URL as "%25"? Percent sign is used to encode special characters, so you must encode the sign itself too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

[Accepting an encoded URL in a Laravel 4 route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851825/accepting-an-encoded-url-in-a-laravel-4-route):

As @Phil Sparks mentioned you can do this:

```
Route::get('add/{encoded_url}', function($encoded_url)
{
    return 'The URL is: '.rawurldecode($encoded_url);
})->where('encoded_url', '.*');
```

Also check ben's answer.